# Microservices teams - how to handle "infrastructure" teams?

Tags: infrastructure

so my question is more related to the teams themselves, and not especially code.

Let's say we have several teams which are "services" related, in that concept the 2 main bullets are:

- Teams should be independent - can do everything alone, find reusable code probably, and write anything they needed.
- Teams should have defined set of responsibilities.

So, when i'm thinking about it, it kinda looks like an old concept, where team has 1 product, can they touch other "infrastructures?"

there should be specific teams that are responsible on the infra, right? as if another team touches the infra while developing - they might not do a great job, as they don't have a connection to that area.

So, the questions are: what if a developer team is responsible on an infrastructure service:

1. How does it relate to the claim that teams should be independent? If they need a feature from the infrastructure – they need to ask the infra team to develop it for them? Do they develop inside infra? (which breaks the team focus & they are not experts in the infra)? Maybe they bypass it somehow – which might be problematic aswell.
2. What’s usually the focus on an infrastructure service team? Don’t they get their feature requests from other developers teams - Which then makes them a bottleneck and other teams will be stuck?

i wonder to start a discussion about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two paise based on what I've experienced :

1. Each service team should be given access to certain part of infrastructure. Say in the context of cloud, access to a tenant with a bunch of resource allocated to it. This will help the team spin a VM as per their needs.
2. Infra team should be present to investigate and maintain the infra at a higher level, say increase the resource allocation to a tenant, make a certain kind of OS available, investigate a service malfunctioning, etc..
3. Towards common technology stacks such as CI/CD, the responsibility of maintainence and upkeep of the system would be with the infra team. However addition of any listeners would be with the 'service team'. In this way, a service team would only have to contact infra team when there is system wide disruption and not pertaining to day-to-day changes.

Comment: but doesn't the infra team becomes a bottleneck? i didn't understand from the answer if the services teams should be allowed to touch the internals of the infra team (as they are not professional in that area)

Comment: @ArielB I would say the service team shouldn't be bothered with the internals of the infrastructure, say for example (in the context of the cloud) the upkeep of cloud OS, networking, etc. However my comment holds good only in cases where cloud is extensively used for infrastructure needs.

Comment: i'm referring to a feature that doesn't exist in the infra team, so in currently - we let services touch the infra and add the feature (with help of someone from infra) - but if it's done - the infra team will only do maintenance? this will make the team be unhappy

Comment: I feel if the feature is something which is used only by that particular service team then it is a good idea to let them along with the team members to implement it. But if the feature if something which is used cross service teams then I feel Infra team alone is responsible for implementing it.

Comment: Yeah, i feel that way too, but if services team needs a big feature that requires big feature in infra, infra wouldnt always be able to do it. meaning, the services team is stuck... as not always they have the skill to do it themselves..